# PostgreSQL simply transpose/convert rows to columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I read some SO posts like [sql server 2008 r2 - Transpose rows to columns - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970894/transpose-rows-to-columns) or [sql - Postgres - Transpose Rows to Columns - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns), but they are too complicated task to what I want to implement, and what I want to is pretty simple task.

For example, assume I have something like following one:

```
value
1
2
3
```

I want to convert the above to something like this:

```
tmp, tmp02, tmp03
1, 2, 3
```

The columns, tmp to tmp03, can be manually assigned for me, since the data I'm trying to is 4 or 5 of these, just simpler the sqi is the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pivot query with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE rn = 1) AS tmp,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE rn = 2) AS tmp02,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE rn = 3) AS tmp03
FROM cte;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo